# disabling scroll on arrow up and down

Tags: javascript

is there a way to disable scrolling when pressing the arrow up and down keys?

Comment: If there is, please don't do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible (see http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1262956&page=1), but please, for the love of God, limit it to the particular section where it's a problem.

The script would look something like this (taken from the link earlier):

```
<script>
if(window.Event) window.captureEvents(Event.KEYDOWN);

function keyDown(e){
  var n = (window.Event) ? e.which : e.keyCode;
  if(n==38 || n==40) return false;
}
</script>

<select onkeydown="return keyDown(event);" onmousewheel="return false">
<option>a
<option>b
<option>c
</select>
```

There are responsible applications for this idea. Please make sure yours is one of them.